# If statement in an html template

Tags: email-template, html, if

I'm trying to add some logic to our templates but there doesn't seem to be much documentation about this topic.

The syntax I'm using is the following:

```
{!IF(QA_Ninjas__c.Entities_Agregados__c>0,"Entities agregados:  "+QA_Ninjas__c.Entities_Agregados__c+"<br/>","")}
```

I read somewhere that this only works for text and I'm using a number field here. Am I using the correct syntax or is there another way to get the same result? Currently nothing displays when I send the email.

Answer (score 1):

It's doable but you won't like the answer. As far as I know there's no `IF()`. You can use `NullValue` (probably also `BlankValue`). So - to achieve what you're after you'd need to waste a formula field to store your ">0" logic.

Here's an Account-related HTML template I've just made:

```
{!Account.Name} : {!NullValue(Account.NumberOfEmployees, "(no data)")}
```

If wasting so many fields is not an option - consider making a Visualforce template. As your logic grows more complex you'll probably want to show/hide whole sections anyway (`rendered` attribute).

Couple other things that bit me in the past:

1. Check the real body of template (with Eclipse IDE or by querying the the `EmailTemplate` table by Id) & if you're stuck - post here the relevant bit exactly as it is.
2. What do you use to edit the template? Often the online editor tries to be helpful & injects `<span>,<font>,<div>` tags in all the wrong places, rendering your logic useless. MS Word is especially infamous for inserting this rubbish. Use a text editor (Notepad++?) and save directly via Eclipse, no copy-pasting.

Comment: +1 for the VF Email Template suggestion; it is super annoying that the formula merge fields don't work consistently across all email template types